# flutter play mpg / mpeg / mov video format

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/chewie to play video, it's fine with mp4 format but for mpeg mpg or mov it only shows black screen. i tried with original video_player it gave the same result. any thought for this?

https://storage.googleapis.com/tvri-dev-assets/AYO%20KE%20MUSEUM/AKM21_001A.mpg

```
Future<void> initializePlayer() async {
    _videoPlayerController1 =
        VideoPlayerController.network(srcs[currPlayIndex]);
    _videoPlayerController2 =
        VideoPlayerController.network(srcs[currPlayIndex]);
    await Future.wait([
      _videoPlayerController1.initialize(),
      _videoPlayerController2.initialize()
    ]);
    _createChewieController();
    setState(() {});
  }
```